# Spring Boot upgrade to 2.6.0 not compatible with Spring Cloud release train

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud

We're trying to upgrade spring boot version to 2.6.0 and faced up with "Spring Boot [2.6.0] is not compatible with this Spring Cloud release train" (when running integration tests).

In additional

- spring-cloud.version = 2020.0.4
- We're using org.springframework.cloud (spring-cloud-context & spring-cloud-commons) 3.0.4
- And have (also) this block in the pom:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
      <exclusions>
         <exclusion>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
         </exclusion>
         <exclusion>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
         </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

Actually I didn't find in [Spring docs](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud#overview) compobility between Spring Cloud and Spring Boot 2.6.0, it's sound very odd but Have I wait for newest spring cloud version or I can beat it?

P.S. :

SDK: Java 8

Other tries (each was tried separately):

- `spring.profiles.active=native`
- `spring.cloud.compatibility-verifier.enabled=false`

Comment: You have to wait for a compatible version, also if you are using the parent/bom why include the explicit version of the cloud parts? Those should come from the bom.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks. zuul using org.springframework.cloud 2.2.9 RELASE, I tried force use 3.0.4 (hope to solve the issue but not..)

Comment: @AsfK zuul is no longer part of Spring Cloud

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It will be released on November 30 2021. See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/milestones?direction=asc&sort=due_date&state=open

Comment: It was not released, I guess there is a delay?

Comment: You could found  information about compatibility of versions of Spring Boot and Spring Cloud here: [https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud#overview](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud#overview)

Answer (score 7):

You need spring cloud dependencies 2021.0.0 which is now available.

Comment: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud should be updated to reflect this if this is true.

Answer (score 0):

You can add "spring.cloud.compatibility-verifier.enabled=false" in your src/test/resources/application.properties